# PyCharm выдает ошибку.Можете подсказать как исправить?

Tags: python, pycharm

> Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system
>   codec LookupError: no codec search functions registered: can't find
>   encoding
>
> Current thread 0x00000bec (most recent call first):

Comment: Проверьте переменные среды `PYTHONPATH` и `PYTHONHOME`. Вы должны убедиться, что они не указывают на Python 2.x.x

Comment: Думаю, PyCharm тут не при чём.

Comment: При каких обстоятельствах возникает ошибка? Работает ли Python вне PyCharm?